# How do I rip a backup of an HD-DVD? (yes, the old format that was killed by Blu-ray)

Tags: video, backup

I have some old HD-DVDs lying around. I'd like to put them on my computer as a digital file. I'm familiar with Handbrake, and the process of ripping DVDs. But not HD-DVDs. I'm using the Xbox 360 HD-DVD player, which has a USB straight into my PC.

Comment: No, that's how to rip a Blu-ray. I'm looking for how to rip a HD-DVD, a totally different format.

Answer (score -1):

This is how you back up HD DVDs but you will notice that the video and audio is VC1 and either EAC1 DDP or AC1 DD which for some reason not all media players support despite them both being quite popular.

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://m.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3Dbq1kQgapF6Q&ved=2ahUKEwiLpKrlsob9AhUwlYkEHYdjBNkQjjh6BAgOEAI&usg=AOvVaw0X9SGC37soo72Ju4gi7Wl1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).